# Clicking ASP.NET button causes page to display in Quirks Mode for IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an ASP.NET button. When the button is clicked it sends an email to the webmaster.

**My Problem:** In IE9 after the button is clicked, the page refreshes and then displays the page in compatibility mode. Which means divs and images are out of place.

How can I stop IE9 from displaying my page in compatibility mode(is it quirks mode?)? My webpage even uses the suggested doc type for IE9 which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The button is:

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:button id="btnSave" OnClick="bt1Clicked" runat="server" Text="Send"  type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></asp:button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Weird, you can try using the `X-UA-Compatible` attribute.

Put this in your `<head>`:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

This should force IE to use the latest (IE9) rendering.

You can read more about this attribute at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx